# IQueryable does not append WHERE statement in SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm using the EF6 with a MySQL server. I'm trying to dynamically append WHERE clauses based on the variable being null or not.
This is my code:

```
using (var dbContext = new Entities())
{
    IQueryable<Boxes> boxes = dbContext.Boxes;

    if(this.Customer != null)
        boxes.Where(box => box.CurrentCustomer == this.Customer);    

    if(this.IDs != null)
        boxes.Where(box => this.IDs.Split(',').Any(id => id == box.ID.ToString()));  

    return new Response() { Success = true, Result = boxes.ToList() };
}
```

However the data is not being filtered by the WHERE clause and all rows from the table are being returned. Also in the MySQL log I see the statement which does not include a WHERE clause:

```
1994 Query SELECT
`Extent1`.`ID`,
`Extent1`.`CurrentCustomer`
FROM `Boxes` AS `Extent1`
```

Am I using the `IQueryable` wrong?

Comment: are you sure `this.Customer` and `this.Ids` are not null?

Comment: In Linq, `.Where` actually returns a result.

Comment: Absolutely. Did step by step debugging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save your query when you call `Where` method:

```
IQueryable<Boxes> boxes = dbContext.Boxes;

if(this.Customer != null)
   boxes= boxes.Where(box => box.CurrentCustomer == this.Customer);    

if(this.IDs != null)
    boxes=boxes.Where(box => this.IDs.Split(',').Any(id => id == box.ID.ToString())); 
//...
```

Comment: Well.. that's going to be in my top 10 of things I wasted my time with :D Thank you!